# how to use check_required_components in cmake?

Tags: cmake

The `configure_package_config_file` is a specialized version of `configure_file`, which transforms a `<name>Config.cmake.in` (or other named) template into a `<name>Config.cmake`. The user provides the template `<name>Config.cmake.in`, which can use specific macros like `check_required_components`.

The `check_required_components(<PackageName>)` requires a package name. The `configure_package_config_file` provides the definition of `check_required_components` during the file transformation process. Its definition is as follows:

```
macro(check_required_components _NAME)
  foreach(comp ${${_NAME}_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    if(NOT ${_NAME}_${comp}_FOUND)
      if(${_NAME}_FIND_REQUIRED_${comp})
        set(${_NAME}_FOUND FALSE)
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endmacro()
```

This definition checks the value of `${_NAME}_${comp}_FOUND`, so the question is when is `${_NAME}_${comp}_FOUND` defined?

Originally, it was thought to be defined during the execution of the install command, for example in the following cmake listfile:

```
install(TARGETS math
    EXPORT mymath_export_set
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} COMPONENT lib
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} COMPONENT headers
)
```

When executing `cmake --install <build-tree> --prefix=<install-dir> --component=lib` in the terminal, it was thought that cmake would define `math_lib_FOUND` as `TRUE`.

However, it was found that this is not the case, and cmake does not define the value of `math_lib_FOUND` from start to finish.

In another project, when using `find_package` for searching, there is:

```
find_package(math 1.2.3 REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS lib
    PATHS <install-dir>
)
```

If `COMPONENTS` is not provided, then `check_required_components` will pass; if an non-existent `COMPONENTS` is provided, such as `dev`, `config`, `runtime`, etc., then `check_required_components` will also pass; but if an existing `COMPONENTS` is provided, such as `lib` or `headers` here, then `check_required_components` will not pass.

Not being able to pass means that it will set `${_NAME}_FOUND` to `FALSE`. The key problem is that `math_lib_FOUND` should be provided as `TRUE`, but it is not, so according to the logic of `check_required_components`, `${_NAME}_FOUND` can only be `FALSE`.

So what exactly is cmake thinking, and how to use the `check_required_components` macro? Do users need to manually provide the definition of `math_lib_FOUND` as `TRUE`? Or is there some trick that I haven’t understood yet?